# PTR record not valid for all domains

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange-2010, smtp, ptr-record

We have an issue sending emails to certain domains, namely Time Warner and Cox. Last week, we decommissioned our Exchange 2003 server and now our Exchange 2010 server is doing all of the transport for our domain.  We run our own authoritative name servers, so we are in charge of the DNS and have modified our PTR record to reflect the new server. All mailflow is working except for these 2 domains.

When I telnet on port 25 to the mail servers for Cox and Time Warner I am receiving errors. For Cox the error is:
554... rejected - no rDNS

And when I telnet to port 25 to the Time Warner mail server we get this:
554 5.7.1 - Connection refused. IP name lookup failed for x.x.x.x

I have run through the outbound SMTP test on Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer and get 100% completely successful results.  MXToolbox comes up with all successful tests on SMTP as well, showing correct reverse banner check, and no blacklisting.  DNSQueries.com shows a valid reverse DNS entry as well for us.

Outbound emails to these 2 domains continue to sit in the queue.  Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to include the IP address.

Comment: So you're saying that you manage the Reverse Lookup Zone for your ip address block? If so, have you verified that the correct delegation has been set up for that block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your ISP and ask them to update the PTR record for your IP address with the hostname of your mailserver...

Comment: Thank you but we are the authoritative name servers for the domain.  This was fixed by adjusting the PTR record on our DNS servers.

Comment: The point (as joeqwerty was hinting) is that although your DNS is authoritative for your domain, it's unlikely to be authoritative for z.y.x.w.in-addr.arpa which is the reverse record for your IP.